Cats from the neighborhood running out to save people from danger
There is this movie I remembered recently, that I've seen as a child around 1996 and 2000. I remember it had a horror/suspense theme, but I can only remember a scene that was probably near the end, which shows a lot of cats from a simple neighborhood (like suburban or something), leaving their houses to fight together against something evil (don't remember what). It was when the people were being dominated or killed, so they came at last as their saviors.
I always thought it was a scene from Village of the Damned, but I searched around and found no reference of this, couldn't find the whole movie on YouTube to check accurately.
Another thing, it is a real movie, not animated, it looked like it was at least from before 2000 but not that old I think.
Which movie could this be?

Maybe Stephen King's Sleepwalkers, from 1992?  The "mother-and-son team of strange supernatural creatures" could only be killed by cat scratches, and lots of cats seemed to be drawn to wherever they were living.  Note the cats on the poster:


Even though I only saw a part of the cat running scene, I confirmed that this is the right movie. You are amazing, Will. Thanks. :)
